# Test suite failed to run with @react-navigation/stack

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation-v5

I started writing unit testing in React Native app. I created new project in Typescript using the following command.

> npx react-native init rn_jest --template
> react-native-template-typescript

When i executed npm test in root of project i got the below results

> PASS  **tests**/App-test.tsx (7.472s)   ✓ renders correctly (4329ms)
> Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
> Snapshots:   0 total Time:        7.64s Ran all test suites.

Next i integrated [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) in app and executed npm test again, but this time i got following error

> FAIL  **tests**/App-test.tsx   ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> /Users/macbookpro/Documents/Manheium_Express/rn_jest/node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/views/assets/back-icon.png:1
> �PNG
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>
>   at Runtime._execModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1157:58)
> ```
>
> console.error
> react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure you're running your app on the native platform and your code is linked
> properly (cd ios && pod install && cd ..).
>
> ```
> For installation instructions, please refer to https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation
>
>   at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/commonjs/RNGestureHandlerModule.ts:5:3)
> ```
>
> Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total Tests:       0 total Snapshots:   0
> total Time:        3.229s Ran all test suites. npm ERR! Test failed.
> See above for more details.

I checked this [link](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8669) and not found any solution. here is code inside App-test.tsx file

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

Below is the package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.18.1"
  },
```

I followed this [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/testing/) also but no luck. if any one has solved this issue in unit test using jest please help me out

Answer (score 3):

I handled that issue by following Jest documentation:

[Testing with Jest](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/testing/)

And following the Handling Static Assets section from this doc:

[Handling Static Assets](https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets)

My package.json looks like:

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/jest/setup.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
```

Finally, I ran:

```
yarn jest
```

Comment: Mocking only static assets solved my problem.